# Improving my Delete function in my repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a DeleteUser function **with a bool return value**. My ORM is Entity Framework. As you can see below, I force the true value at the end of the function which is not quite pretty well. How can I proceed to place this return (bool) value only when the SaveChanges do his job (deleting the user)? Maybe a try...catch? Another solution?

```
    public bool DeleteUser(string username)
    {
        User user = m_context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();
        m_context.Users.Remove(user);
        m_context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best approach but you can confirm the deleted user doing this:

```
public bool DeleteUser(string username)
{
    User user = m_context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();
    m_context.Users.Remove(user);
    m_context.SaveChanges();

    User deletedUser = m_context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();

    if (deletedUser == null)
       return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try...catch should work:

```
public bool DeleteUser(string username)
{
    try
    {
        User user = m_context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();
        m_context.Users.Remove(user);
        m_context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Returning a boolean won't give you the reason for the exception, however.